# Change a default style of checkbox in firefox

Tags: firefox

I have too big checkboxes in my Firefox 66 browser

[image: Example]

How to scale down the default checkboxes, or change their default style in the way it will work for any web page.

For example on chromium browser, this page looks like:

[image]

HTML:

[image]

Comment: Please share your CSS and HTML code.

Comment: I updated the description @LucienDubois

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

As it seems to display well in Chrome, try to disable the default appearance. Use this in your CSS file:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    -moz-appearance:none;
}
```

Further reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/appearance).

Comment: In this case, checkboxes disappeared at all. I tried also `-webkit-appearance: none;` without success

Comment: another problem here is how to make this css style applied by default to any web page